# Android AES crypt 192bit key

Tags: android, aes

I want to encrypt the data using a 192-bit key.

```
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(new byte[]{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, "AES/CBC/NoPadding");
byte[] data = new byte[] {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
byte[] encrypted = null;
try {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

But encryption is not true. Moreover the contents of the array each time is different. Why?

Comment: What do you mean with "not true" ?

Comment: How do you init your KeyGenerator?

Comment: >>What do you mean with "not true" 
Encryption result is different from the same in C++

>> How do you init your KeyGenerator?
I am not generating key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using CBC mode, which requires an initialization vector (IV). Since you don't set one explicitly, a random one is generated each time your encrypt. You have to either:

- use a static IV (not recommended), or
- send the IV along with the cipher text to the C++ program

Here is how to set the IV in Java, for C++ refer to the documentation of the library you are using:

```
 byte[] iv = generateIv(cipher.getBlockSize());
 IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivParams);
```